# tsql : can't select into <table> from proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running sql server 2008 and I'm trying to run the query

```
OPEN CUR_InvHeader
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_InvHeader INTO 
    @CH_iBilling_Log_RecID
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN        --Loop for Cur_InvHeader

select * into tarInvoiceDetail_201101 FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC _sp_cwm5_GetInvoiceDetail @CH_iBilling_Log_RecID')
```

I get the error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked
>   server "(null)" returned message
>   "Deferred prepare could not be
>   completed.".

I've run sp_configure 'ad hoc..', 1 
reconfigure with override 
to ensure i can run the select against the openrecordset

any ideas what i might be doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: see those cursors?  you are going to TSQL hell! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that's wrong is that your "EXEC _sp_cwm5_GetInvoiceDetail @CH_iBilling_Log_RecID" statement will be evaluated as a constant, rather than pass the value of @CH_iBilling_Log_RecID through to OPENROWSET. You'd have to replace the whole "SELECT * INTO..." into a string variable and run sp_executesql on it.

The second thing wrong is that your "select into" statement will create tarInvoiceDetail_201101 every time, as INTO creates a new table when run. So if your cursor covers more than one row you'll get an error on the second pass.

Also, what does "Server=(local)" represent here? Are you trying to use OPENROWSET against your local copy of SQL Server while connected to a remote server? Or are you trying to use OPENROWSET to get around the limitation that you can't directly use a stored procedure as the source for an INSERT?

Comment: the Server=(local) represents the local server instance.  I'm trying to use openrowset to work around selecting into a new table from a sproc

Comment: @phill: And how do you account for the fact that you are doing the insert inside the loop through a cursor? Do you remove that table towards the end of the loop? For if you don't, you cannot SELECT INTO it again, that would produce an error.